# Phonegap storage , does db exist

Tags: cordova

Ok so this is my first app for ios using the storage functions in phonegap. I have used phonegap before but never with storage.

As I start to dive in the first thing I need to do is create the db on the device ready. Now my question before I even get started is when i do window.openDatabase is that going to create the db every time? Or if the db by the name I specify exists does it just skip it?

Oh and also is there a command to simply check if the db is there?

Answer (score 1):

if the database version provided is the empty string, or if the database doesn't yet exist, or if the database exists and the version provided to the openDatabase() method is the same as the current version associated with the database, then the method must return a Database object representing the database that has the name that was given. If no such database exists, it must be created first.

This is from the original documentation and works as mentioned - http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090212/structured-client-side-storage.html

As such there is no direct method to know whether database is exist or not, but you can check whether a table is exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap/Cordova use the default database provided by the WebView (the chromeless browser instance the iOS SDK provides: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

When you do a `window.openDatabase("mydatabase", "1.0", "PhoneGap", 0);`

It creates a database(`0000000000000001.db`) at this location

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.3/Applications/E56D5D30-2F7F-4B28-A139-2FBE979C2B10/Library/WebKit/Databases/file__0

Your all tables will be stored here.